# Getting the menu to float right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to get the menu to display on the right side of the bar instead of the left.  I have tried several things...

Here is the working script (except the menu is not on the right like I want it)...
http://jsfiddle.net/8Y4DH/5/

I have tried adjusting UL and LI css...

```
.fusion ul{
clear: both;
float:right !important;
margin-top: 0px !important;
margin-right: 0px !important;
margin-bottom: 0px !important;
margin-left: auto !important;
padding: 0px;
z-index: 1000;
max-height: 65px !important;
min-height: 65px !important;
}
```

and then set the LI to float left but this did nothing at all.  Then I tried setting the LI to float right but then the menu just displayed backwards (which also disrupted the first:child and last:child settings in the css).  I have no idea how to get this to work right because all the things I normally do will not work on this script.

Can someone please help.  I've tried getting this to work for the past few days and I am nearly ready to give up.  And I can't just make the menu display backward and then put the menu items in reverse order because this messes up another script that I will be putting in in order to make the menu mobile responsive under certain dimensions.  Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your CSS like below.

```
.fusion ul{
clear: both;
float:right !important;
margin-top: 0px !important;
margin-right: 0px !important;
margin-bottom: 0px !important;
margin-left: auto !important;
padding: 0px;
z-index: 1000;
max-height: 65px !important;
min-height: 65px !important;
width:auto !important; /* this will override the 100% inline style */
right:0; /* this will align right the menu */
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8Y4DH/11/)

Comment: Wow... I didnt even notice that the width was set at 100%.  That's the missing piece here.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Change your js to following:

```
if(settings.bar != 'aside'){
            navbar.css({
                'position':'relative',
            });
        }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Y4DH/13/)

Just remove `width:100%`

Answer (score 0):

Please check the fiddle, you have set the value of

```
. fusion ul li{
    display: inline;
        margin-right: 15px;
        padding: 22px 0;
        float:left !important;}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8Y4DH/8/)

change to:

```
.fusion ul li{
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding: 22px 0;
    float:right !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `width 100%` (so its `auto` again) and `position: absolute` on your `<ul>` (so it will be `static` again).